# Break String on full stop

Tags: regex, string

I want to break a string on `.` (full stop).

Ex. `String str="We are going there.How are you."`

then output should be

```
We are going there.
How are you.
```

It should split on "."
But if my string is

`Dr.Harry is going.` then it should not break like

```
Dr.
Harry is going.
```

It should be `Dr.Harry is going.` as it is.

just like I have some words, if they come in string then it should not break

```
StringBuffer regex = new StringBuffer("Dr[\\.]|Gr[\\.]|[Aa][\\.][Mm][\\.]|"+ "[Pp][\\.][Mm][\\.]|Emp[\\.]|Rs[\\.]|Ms[\\.]|No[\\.]|Nos[\\.]|"+ "Dt[\\.]|Sh[\\.]|(Mr|mr)[\\.]|(Mrs|mrs)[\\.]|Admn[\\.]|Ad[\\.]|Smt[\\.]|"+ "GOVT[\\.]|Govt[\\.]|Deptt[\\.]|Tel[\\.]|Secy[\\.]|Estt[\\.]|"+ "Asstt[\\.]|Hqrs[\\.]|DY[\\.]|Supdt[\\.]|w[\\.]e[\\.]f[\\.]|"+ "I[\\.]|N[\\.]|[0-9]+[\\.][0-9]+[\\.][0-9]|K[\\.]|NSI[\\.]|"+ "Prof[\\.]|Dte[\\.]|no[\\.]|nos[\\.]|Agri[\\.]|R[\\.]|"+ "K[\\.]|Y[\\.]|C[\\.]|N[\\.]|Dept[\\.]|S[\\.]|Spl[\\.]|N[\\.]|"+ "Sr[\\.]|Addl[\\.]|i[\\.]e[\\.]|Sl[\\.]|CS[\\.]|M[\\.]|IPS[\\.]|"+ "Jt[\\.]|viz[\\.]|hrs[\\.]|S/Sh[\\.]|Jr[\\.]|E[\\.]|S[\\.]|"+ "Pers[\\.]|Deptts[\\.]|OM[\\.]|DT[\\.]|Proj[\\.]|Instrum[\\.]|"+ "Div[\\.]|Dev[\\.]|Env[\\.]|e[\\.]g[\\.]|etc[\\.]|Misc[\\.]|"+ "vig[\\.]|Dr[\\.]|Nos[\\.]|Ltd[\\.]|Maj[\\.]|"+ "Gen[\\.]|MAJ[\\.]|GEN[\\.]|Su[\\.]|/Ess[\\.]|Com[\\.]|St[\\.]|");
```

these are some words in which string should not split if they come. just like Dr.Harry is going.
Any regular expression is possible ?
or any other method ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this :

search : `(?<!(Mr|Dr|Gr|Aa))\.`

replace : `\n`

you can add as many words you want using `|` after the `Aa`.

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/fP6hN9

I tried the code below and its working fine for me:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
    String str1 = "We are going there.How are you.Mr.Gordon is also coming with us.Are you sure you want to take him", str2;
    String substr = "\n", regex = "(?<!(Mr|Dr|Gr|Aa))\\.";

    // prints string1
    System.out.println("String = " + str1);

    /* replaces each substring of this string that matches the given
    regular expression with the given replacement */
    str2 = str1.replaceAll(regex, substr);    
    System.out.println("After Replacing = " + str2);
    }
}
```

outputs :

```
We are going there
How are you
Mr.Gordon is also coming with us
Are you sure you want to take him
```

checked here :  http://ideone.com/YfLU7v

Comment: thanks.but my replaceall() giving error during rplace.
String strreplace=str.replaceAll((?<!(Mr|Dr|Gr|Aa)\\.), "\n"); 
any correction ?

Comment: @user3441816 is this java ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
(?<!(Dr|Gr|Aa|Mm|Pp))\.
```

Fill in the rest as required. This uses [Lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)